# WordPress - SEO - does turning off comments matter on a non comment template?

Tags: seo, wordpress, comments

I have a custom WordPress themed website.  None of my page/post/category/tag/etc. template pages have any code that has anything to do with comments (as far as I know).

I am wondering if there is anything wrong with leaving "Allow Comments" on for each post/page entry when creating a new page/post or is there a good reason I should un-check this for each?

Comment: Yes you have to allow comments on each post, It help you from traffic point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SEO-specific reason to disable comments based on your statement above.  However, if you ever pass control of the site over to someone else and they install a standard theme, all of those "left-on" pages and posts will revert to being open to comments and you certainly wouldn't want that to happen.

Best practice is to disable comments for all new posts/pages in Settings | Discussion and quickly disable existing content by batch edit.  Think of it as a form of future-proofing.  Also, "as far as I know" is always a dangerous distance :)

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to disable the comments in Settings -> Discussion page so that you don't have them to pop up when some other kind of changes are made to your WordPress website.

SEO rankings will not be affected if you disable these comments. Search spiders will only look into the template part of the website and if it does not have any comments that is fine. They will not be digging the core WordPress files.

Comment: Yah, I wasn't worried about engines digging the core files but rather thought there might be some supplementary comment map (like a sitemap or something) page that WP might generate that I don't know about, or some other such thing that technology tends to surprise me with.  Thank you for the answer!